# Как оптимизировать запрос: самые просматриваемые записи за неделю?

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно отобразить самые просматриваемые новости за последнюю неделю. Запрос рабочий, но выполняется он около минуты. В базе больше полутора миллион записей.

Как можно оптимизировать запрос, может есть вариант использовать другой запрос?

Индекс стоит на всех полях.
Индекс city_url - уникальных элементов 599
Индекс time - уникальных элементов 1633941
Индекс views - уникальных элементов 15

```
SELECT *
FROM news
WHERE city_url like '$city'
  AND time > unix_timestamp(date_sub(current_date, interval 1 week))
ORDER BY views DESC limit 3
```

Comment: Что значит "индекс на всех полях", это один индекс или много ? Если один, то в каком порядке в нем поля ? Если на каждую колонку - то вы надеюсь знаете, что в одном запросе может использоваться только один индекс по одной таблице. А много индексов замедляют работу. Что у вас в переменной $city ? если там маска и она начинается с знака `%` то индекс использован быть не может. И покажите план выполнения запроса, который получается командой `explain` и с которого надо начинать любую оптимизацию

Comment: Выполнил explain: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/12/21/0025/0454/1659334/34/3d34cdd420.jpg  Странно, что в phpmyadmin запрос выполнился очень быстро, а на сайте может выполняться минуту, а может и быстро.

Comment: План мягко говоря странный. Боюсь он по всей таблице может бежать в порядке убывания views. вообще не понимаю почему он взял такой порядок. Конкретно для данного запроса оптимальным был бы индекс из двух полей `(city_url, time)` и написать `order by city_url, views DESC` что бы он не мог индекс по views использовать. Впрочем этот индекс лучшее вообще удалить, 1/15 таблицы по нему это все равно огромный объем и вряд ли вы выполняете поиски where views=X, так что он не применим ни в каких случаях и только вредит вот в этом конкретном

Comment: Это конечно при условии, что вы всегда ищете город на строгое равенство, т.е. не используете маску. А что бы это явно указать стоило бы в запросе заменить like на `=`, это то же может сбивать оптимизатор с толку

Comment: *В базе больше полутора миллион записей.* А сколько записей отбирает запрос без LIMIT? *в phpmyadmin запрос выполнился очень быстро* Да небось результат из кэша выпал...

Comment: @Total Pusher, http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/12/21/0025/0454/1659334/34/e2100c6e43.jpg

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE news` я прошу. `like '$city'` - а что конкретно в `$city`, есть проценты, нет процентов?

Comment: У меня сайт с 600 поддоменами, в них города. В $city просто берется название города из поддомена типа moskva.site.ru. Берется moskva. Получается запрос ищет по всей базе новости где присутствует город moskva в поле city_url

Comment: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/12/21/0025/0454/1659334/34/46c86eafab.jpg

Comment: 1. `city_url LIKE 'moskva'` - это ужас. Перепишите на `city_url = 'moskva'`. 2. Попробуйте `ALTER TABLE bezf ADD KEY idx_c(time, city_url, views);`, затем `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` и выхлоп сюда. Чтобы правильно мерить скорость, `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` - будет "честное" время, а не сколько мускул лазил в кеш. Какое время было "до" оптимизации, и "после"? 3. Перестаньте кидать шоты, оформите в виде текста. Чтобы делать это легко, используйте консоль мускула (`mysql ...`)

Comment: Сделал все, что написали, в итоге делаю SQL_NO_CACHE - Запрос занял 0.0226 сек. Получается оптимизация прошла успешно. А вот как выглядит explain http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/12/21/0025/0454/1659334/34/6100466c30.jpg

Comment: Оптимизация помогла частично. Мой индекс не используется, но замена LIKE на `=` помогла. Колонка `key` - используется ключ `views`, низкоселективный - 15 уникальных. Либо в этом конкретном случае по Омску мало записей. Проверьте на остальных городах. Время засекать так: `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ваш запрос`, а не `EXPLAIN ...` - 0.0226 сек, похоже, это время выполнения `EXPLAIN`. Потом у вас уже другой запрос! В нем `ORDER BY` другой, и тот составной индекс, что я придумал, уже может либо совсем не подходить, либо подходить частично. Я же специально под ваш запрос индекс делал, а вы его поменяли.

Comment: Посмотрите статьи "составной индекс MySQL", чтобы понимать что это такое. Например это https://habr.com/post/70640/